# How to update elements of objects in list using lapply

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a list with four objects each of equal length. I want to update elements of the objects according to element positions stored in a vector which correspond to another vector storing the object names. I can do this with a for loop, but I am wondering how to achieve the same result using `lapply()`. I have tried various attempts without success. Any help is greatly appreciated. MWE as follows:

**EDIT**

The four objects in the list are examples of many other objects I have in my original list. In my original list not all objects are selected. So in `obj.names` only three letters are now sampled to represent this.

```
obj.length <- 20
mylist <- list(a = rep(0, obj.length),
               b = rep(0, obj.length),
               c = rep(0, obj.length),
               d = rep(0, obj.length))

set.seed(27)
position <- sample(1:obj.length, 10)                         # elements to update
obj.names <- sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE)        # corresponding object names for which the elements need to updated

for(i in unique(obj.names)){                                 # achieved here
  mylist[[i]][position[obj.names == i]] <- 99 
}

lapply(...)                                                  # but what to do here in order to achieve the same result as in for loop?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `split` the 'position' by 'obj.names' and use `Map` to replace the values in 'mylist' based on the corresponding `list` element positions from the `split` output

```
newlist <- split(position, obj.names)
mylist[names(newlist)] <- Map(`[<-`, mylist[names(newlist)], newlist, 99)
mylist
#$a
# [1] 99  0  0  0 99  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 99  0

#$b
# [1]  0  0 99  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 99  0  0  0  0  0

#$c
# [1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 99 99  0  0  0 99 99  0  0  0 99  0  0

#$d
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

Or using `lapply` with similar looping on the `unique` 'obj.names' as in the OP's `for` loop

```
mylist[unique(obj.names)] <- lapply(unique(obj.names), function(nm) {
       mylist[[nm]][position[obj.names == nm]] <- 99
       mylist[[nm]]
        })
mylist
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. But this is not entirely what I am looking for. First, in the for loop, the objects in the list are updated. In your answers, the list is printed in the console and the objects in the list are actually not updated. Second, in some cases, not all objects need to have elements update. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @altfi_SU that is a property of `for` loop (side effect - it can be an advantage or disadvantage based on the. problem) to update the original object.  If you want to update.  you need to assign `mylist <- lapply(uniique(obj.names), ..`

Comment: @altfi_SU updated for the second case, it is only a small change i.e. to use only the names of the `split` output to update mylist

Comment: Really nice, thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for. I have never come across `Map` and `split` before. I'll look into them a little more.

Comment: Hi @akrun, please can you point me in the direction to find more information on how the string operator function (i.e. `"[<-"`) used in `Map()` works? I am trying to search around on the internet but can't find any info. I think it's because the search terms I am using are wrong - illustrating my lack of knowledge when it comes to this.

Comment: @altfi_SU it is just a short hand to do the assignment.  You can make it more easily understandable with lamdba functions ie. `Map(function(x, y) replace(x, y,  99), mylist[names(newlist)], newlist)`